# Why is jsp page showing ? for text than cannot be encoded as ISO-8859-1 such as Chinese

Tags: java, jsp, utf-8, character-encoding

Why is jsp page showing ? for or text than cannot be encoded as ISO-8859-1, even though my jsp has :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

the jsp page is http://www.albunack.net/ and you can see the problem by entering chuan into the **artist name** field and pressing submit.

The weird thing if you then click one of the question marks links it takes you to a page for that artist and correctly renders the chinese characters. So the server (tomcat 8) seems to be setup correctly for rendering UTF8, the difference is that the artist page is rendered by a servlet whereas the search page is a jsp so it seems to be this is a jsp specific issue.

I have the same problem whether Im running locally on my own machine or deployed (as in the above link) to AWS.

**Update 1**
Fixed, problem was that jsp pages were not actually encoded to utf8 (because there was no character in the static content the editor saw no need to use anything other than the default encoding), force saving all jsp files to use UTF-8 and it now works.

**Update 2**
Hmm, the problem has reocurred and I have resaved the jsps and includes to UTF-8 but it hasn't made any difference this time

**Update 3**
Fixed by changing

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html"%>
```

to

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

notclear why I have to do this now though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed ensuring file actually encoded as UTF-8 and by changing

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html"%>
```

to

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```